# How to get chrome cookie headers and values for a specific domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I want to get stored cookies in Chrome using an extension when a download request made. But I don't know how because I am new in Chrome extension development and javascript. How can I do that?

So I have:

> manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "ADM",
  "description": "Get cookies",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
  },
  "permissions": [
    "downloads",
    "cookies"
  ],

  "background": { "scripts": ["myscript.js"], "persistent": false }
}
```

> myscript.js

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (item) {
    chrome.downloads.cancel(item.id);
    alert(document.cookie);
});
```

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (and perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: You'll need to determine which document the download belongs to and I see no such method in the downloads API. Or maybe it's the `referrer` field. Anyway, I haven't tried it.